# Check the render method of 'SeekBar'

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

```
invariant violation element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object
```

Check the render method of **SeekBar**
 [image: Screenshot of my error]

I don't know what my object error is for my `SeekBar` code. Appreciate the help.

```
var Slider = require('react-native-slider');

function pad(n, width, z=0) {
    n = n + '';
    return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

const minutesAndSeconds = (position) => ([
    pad(Math.floor(position / 60), 2),
    pad(position % 60, 2),
]);

const SeekBar = ({
    trackLength,
    currentPosition,
    onSeek,
    onSlidingStart,
    })=> {
        const elapsed = minutesAndSeconds(currentPosition);
        const remaining = minutesAndSeconds(trackLength - currentPosition);
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                  {elapsed[0] + ":" + elapsed[1]}
                </Text>
                <View style={{flex: 1}} />
                <Text style={[styles.text, {width: 40}]}>
                  {trackLength > 1 && "-" + remaining[0] + ":" + remaining[1]}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Slider
                maximumValue={Math.max(trackLength, 1, currentPosition + 1)}
                onSlidingStart={onSlidingStart}
                onSlidingComplete={onSeek}
                value={currentPosition}
                style={styles.slider}
                minimumTrackTintColor='#fff'
                maximumTrackTintColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14)'
                thumbStyle={styles.thumb}
                trackStyle={styles.track}/>
            </View>
        );
};

export default SeekBar;
```

This is my StyleSheet code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    slider: {
        marginTop: -12,
    },
    container: {
        paddingLeft: 16,
        paddingRight: 16,
        paddingTop: 16,
    },
    track: {
        height: 2,
        borderRadius: 1,
    },
    thumb: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    text: {
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72)',
        fontSize: 12,
        textAlign:'center',
    }
});
```

Comment: My guess is  that the slider is undefined. You can maybe try using import instead of require like in this example: https://snack.expo.io/@damasivavaraprasad/react-native-slider-example

Comment: Also make sure to actually import View and Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try import Slider like `import { Slider } from "react-native-slider"` ?

or simply `import Slider from "react-native-slider"` ?